# GKE - scale to 1 issue

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I've created a Kubernetes Cluster on Google Cloud (GKE) - Default Settings, just CSI enabled.
Create a Node-Pool with AutoScaling enabled, VM Size is g1-small.

When i set the Scaling-Range to 0-3 the Pool is scaled down to 0.
When i set the Scaling Range to 1-3 the Pool is always scaled to 2 Instances.

Why i can't scale to 1?
There is no workload running on it!

*I need to write some more Text because Stack thinks there are missing infos. Well this algo is just, not very well written and should be rethinked.*

Comment: Please post the command generated in GCP UI to create the cluster. It will help the community to help you

Comment: Solved after disabling all log-mecahnis! Seems like the pods took to much cpu&ram for one node only!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments:

> Solved after disabling all log-mecahnis!
>
> Seems like the pods took to much cpu&ram for one node only!